# Как объединить столбец БД и Derived Table в запросе (Firebird)

Tags: sql, firebird

На Firebird 2.5 server в БД есть таблицы: goods, income, sale.

- Goods таблица имеет столбцы: goods_id, name
- Income:  Income_id, Goods_id, incomeqty (quantity), recdate
- Sale:  sales_id,income_id,Goods_id,saleqty,recdate

Есть такой запрос,который выбирает приходы,расходы и остатки(разницу):

```
 select income.goods_id,
   sum(case when which = 'income' then sum_amt else 0 end) as sum_income,
   sum(case when which = 'sale' then sum_amt else 0 end) as sum_sale,
   sum(case when which = 'income' then sum_amt else 0 end)
 - sum(case when which = 'sale' then sum_amt else 0 end) as differ_between
 from (select goods_id, sum(incomeqty) as sum_amt, 'income' as which
         from income
        where income.recdate betwwen :d1 and :d2         
        group by pr_k
        union all
       select goods_id, sum(salesqty), 'sale'
         from sales
        where sale.recdate between :d1 and :d2 
        group by goods_id) x
 group by goods_id
```

но как добавить в запросе из goods таблицы  goods "name" и `if clause("where goods_id=income.goods_id")`?

---

**UPDATE1**

Вроде запрос уже создал, но одна проблема: если в интервале нет прихода и/или расхода, тогда DBGrid пустой, т.е. возврашает Null. А я хочу, чтобы GoodsList(список товара) всегда существовал.

```
select income.goods_id,dt2.goods_id,dt2.sum_income,dt2.sum_sales,dt2.differ_between
from goods
INNER JOIN
(select goods_id,
   sum(case when which = 'income' then sum_amt else 0 end) as sum_income,
   sum(case when which = 'sale' then sum_amt else 0 end) as sum_sale,
  sum(case when which = 'income' then sum_amt else 0 end)
 - sum(case when which = 'sale' then sum_amt else 0 end) as differ_between
 from (select goods_id, sum(incomeqty) as sum_amt, 'income' as which
      from income
      where income.recdate between :d1 and :d2         
      group by goods_id
    union all
      select goods_id, sum(salesqty), 'sale'
      from sales
      where sale.recdate between :d1 and :d2 
      group by goods_id) dt1
 group by goods_id
)dt2
on goods.goods_id=dt2.goods_id
```

---

**UPDATE2**

Правильно работает, если в интервале есть приход или/и расход, а если в интервале нет прихода и расхода, тогда поля Goods_id,sum_income, sum_sale, differ_between пустые, т.е. возврашает Null. А я хочу, чтобы GoodsList(список товара) всегда существовал.

```
SELECT g.name, dt2.goods_id, dt2.sum_income, dt2.sum_sales, dt2.differ_between
FROM goods g
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT goods_id,
   sum(sum_income) as sum_income,
   sum(sum_sale) as sum_sale,
   sum(sum_income - sum_sale) as differ_between
 from (select goods_id, sum(incomeqty) as sum_income, 0 as sum_sale, 1 as which
      from income
      where income.recdate between :d1 and :d2         
      group by goods_id
    union all
      select goods_id, 0, sum(salesqty), -1
      from sales
      where sale.recdate between :d1 and :d2 
      group by goods_id) dt1
 group by goods_id
)dt2
on g.goods_id = dt2.goods_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
SELECT g.name, g.goods_id, 
       coalesce(dt2.sum_income,0), coalesce(dt2.sum_sales,0),
       coalesce(dt2.differ_between,0)
FROM goods g
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT goods_id,
   sum(sum_income) as sum_income,
   sum(sum_sale) as sum_sale,
   sum(sum_income - sum_sale) as differ_between
 from (select goods_id, sum(incomeqty) as sum_income, 0 as sum_sale, 1 as which
      from income
      where income.recdate between :d1 and :d2         
      group by goods_id
    union all
      select goods_id, 0, sum(salesqty), -1
      from sales
      where sale.recdate between :d1 and :d2 
      group by goods_id) dt1
 group by goods_id
) dt2 on g.goods_id = dt2.goods_id
```

Comment: **Saidolim** пишет "engine error: column unknown sum_amt".

Comment: @davidkoko исправил проверьте, там поля другие были

Comment: **Saidolim**  правильно работает, если в интервале есть приход или/и расход, а если в интервале нет прихода и расхода, тогда поля Goods_id,sum_income, sum_sale, differ_between пустые, т.е. возврашает Null. Только название товара в строке.(см. Update 2)

Comment: @davidkoko проверьте обновление. теперь, если нет данных товара, там будут по 0ям

Comment: сейчась если в интервале нет прихода и расхода, тогда поле Goods_id пусто.

Comment: @davidkoko так не должно быть, если использовать `g.name, g.goods_id,` может вы использовали `dt2.goods_id`

Comment: ,всё правильно работает. Вы супер. Огромное спасибо!!!